# масштабируется адаптация

Tags: css

уже неделю не могу разобраться ,в чем проблема. я адаптирую сайт ,заливаю на гитхаб и на телефоне просто гигантские буквы,когда пальцами уменьшаю экран ,все нормально становится , проверяю сайт на ноуте ,то же самое,хотя когда в хроме проверяла адаптацию ,все было нормально , почему так происходит? вопрос именно про масштаб , размер букв , перенос и тд буду  .Спасибо доделывать[image: первый экран до уменьшения руками]

Comment: По фоткам на других сайтах гадают..

Comment: `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">` задавайте, и будет всё нормально.